# Docker Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I have a collection of web applications, with each running inside its own Docker Containers. I can access them locally via `http://localhost:9001`, for example. I want to access them remotely via `https://site.example.com`, instead. I have a wildcard Let's Encrypt certificate for `example.com`.

I understand I need Apache to do direct traffic from FQDN to Port. So I have setup a `VirtualHost` (below). Normal web activity seems to work fine. I can navigate the website normally.

However, when I try to login using OAuth (e.g. BitBucket), I get a URI redirect mismatch error. This does not happen when I run this outside of a container. I think there is something wrong with my Proxy setup. Is anyone able to advise how to rectify?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName site.example.com
    ServerSignature Off                                                                                                                        

    ProxyRequests Off                                                                                                                          
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9001/

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

For such use case, [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/?__hstc=265350736.1e2d80ddb5cee19039f2712a5fa8575c.1562169862349.1573610559475.1573785729176.88&__hssc=265350736.2.1573785729176&__hsfp=4145327793#the-traefik-quickstart-using-docker) is a very adapted tool. Coupled with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), you can setup multiple docker containers on the same host, each one having its own endpoint. To access them remotely, you just have then to bind remote host's IP address to all your endpoints (or use a public DNS that does it for you).

Here is a `docker-compose.yml` example using Traefik.

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --api --docker --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

  your_first_container:
    image: <YOUR_IMAGE>
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:site.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=9001"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but could you explain how this solves the problem, sorry?

Comment: Traefik creates an abstraction of the containers ports/FQDN bindings for you, which I assume to be the origin of your issue (but maybe I'm wrong). Could you describe exactly the error you are getting from the OAuth system?